# Is it possible to implement web push notification on the intranet?

Tags: laravel, browser, push-notification, pusher, intranet

I want to add push notifications to my website.

Previously I have implemented push notification using pusher.

But this time the network is **not connected to the internet**. The website runs on an **intranet**.

I have searched but not understanding how to implement push notification on the intranet.

Can anyone kindly give me some reference or workflow of the implementation?

I have used laravel for the site development.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The [Laravel Websockets](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction) package might be what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, I will check out Laravel Websocekts

Comment: @MahbuburRahmanMishal Did you find the solution for it?

Comment: Nope, Later i didn't have to continue with the intranet so I continued with websocket with pusher